# Omnipay and Sagepay Server

Tags: omnipay

I'm struggling with [Omnipay and Sagepay Server](https://github.com/omnipay/sagepay). The [Omnipay example](https://github.com/omnipay/example/blob/master/index.php) code doesn't work with Sagepay Server as the final steps are completed by Sagepay and not the client, and as such can't access session data.

The transaction is registered:

```
$response = $this->gateway->purchase($params)->send();
```

The client is redirected to Sagepay:

```
$response->redirect();
```

The purchase should then be completed by Sagepay:

```
$gateway->completePurchase($params)->send();
$gateway->confirm(URL::to('checkout/complete'));
```

However, $params isn't set. I'm unsure get the transaction parameters details again without a session. Or if I cache $params, how the cache can be retrieved by Sagepay.

Any help will be very appreciated!

Thanks

Comment: Hi Beech, did you get your omnipay/sagepay server integration to work?  I can't seem to figure out what to do to complete the transaction and return data to the sagepay reqest to the notification URL. Can you help?

Comment: Sure, I think I'm a Omnipay Sagepay expert now! Ask a question on SO and send me the link.

Comment: Found [your question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21664657/how-do-i-complete-purchase-with-omnipay-sagepay-using-sagepay-server-inframe/21699380#21699380), hope that helped.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to store the transaction details in your database before redirecting customers.

When you first create the transaction, store the `id`, `amount`, `currency` etc in your database, before calling `$gateway->purchase()`. You should also generate a unique token/slug for the transaction.

Then, you can set a custom `returnUrl` with the `$params` array. For example, you might set the return URL to `https://www.example.com/checkout/complete/abcdef` (where `abcdef` is the unique token for the current transaction).

Then, when SagePay calls your return URL, you can check the URL for a valid token, and load the transaction details. That way, you can regenerate the `$params` array with the correct `amount` from the original transaction.

For more information on designing the checkout flow, see [Payment handling between requests](https://github.com/burnbright/silverstripe-omnipay/issues/2).

Comment: Ahh! Yes, that is a good idea. I was storing the information in the database after the $gateway->purchase() in order the get the transaction reference first. Should this be stored later on?

Comment: Actually that's a better idea. From memory with sagepay you need to pass the `transactionReference` back with `$params` when you call `completePurchase()`, so it's a good idea to save the database transaction AFTER calling `purchase()`, but BEFORE redirecting your customer to Sagepay.

Comment: Thanks Adrian, that worked a treat. You should update the docs with some of the information in that issue!

Comment: Yeah I know, it's on my todo list. Really need to write a more thorough guide to checkout flow / cart design.

Comment: I wrote a package for handling SagePay, that may be of use https://github.com/academe/sagepay Even if you don't use the code, the description of the process flow and where data is stored and retrieved, is on the front page.